# Adding and using a new dependency (android-percent-support)

Tags: android, dependencies, build.gradle

Im trying to use `com.android.support:percent:22.2.0` as shown here:
https://github.com/JulienGenoud/android-percent-support-lib-sample

I have tried adding the dependency to the build.gradle in many forms but i still get an error:
`no resource identifier found for attribute layout_heightpercent`
when i try to use the sample layouts.

Maybe it will be important to note that i didnt even have build.gradle until i exported the project as Gradle Generated.

The samples should work, also when i googled this problem i came across many other samples and tried them to no avail.

How do i add this dependency? Thank you.

**EDIT** - this is my build.gradle file, which is located on the root of my project (where AndroidManifest.xml is)

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:percent:22.2.0'
}


android {
compileSdkVersion 15
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
    // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
    // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
    // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
    // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
    // by a similar customization.
    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}
}
```

And this is the error when trying to render the layout:
Exception raised during rendering: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
The following classes could not be found:
- android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)

Answer (score 0):

Can you share some code? The attribute seems to be named

```
layout_heightPercent
```

not

```
layout_heightpercent
```

It might just be a misspelling.

EDIT:

You have two dependency blocks

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:22.2.0'
}
```

But the gradle file looks like it's both the projects and the modules in one. You might want to create a new project and see how the structure looks and then apply that to your own.

Comment: I havent shown code lines because there arent really any.. i just copy-paste several sample layouts and all fail for the same reason, so the real question is, how do i make this dependency work?

And regarding your answer, in the question the p is lowercase because i just copied what i searched on google. the original one is upper-cased.

Comment: Where do you add the dependency?

Comment: There are more than one gradle file, and it should be added to the modules gradle. And moreover, the percent property only works within a PercentRelativeLayout.

Comment: I only see one gradle file which is in the root (where AndroidManifest.xml is)

Comment: Seems like you have a problem with the gradle setup. Try to create a new gradle project in Android Studio, then copy paste the source files into that project.

Answer (score 0):

*I am the original poster*

So i forgot to mention earlier i used eclipse. No change to the build.gradle made any difference.

What i did was install android studio and now it works well, while as even importing the gradle project doesnt work.

So in conclusion, installing android studio was a solution for me.